# snapping brush to the next x value? [dc.js]

Tags: dc.js

I have a line chart and data in the form

```
[{
    time: "2016-4-29"
    total: 23242
},
{ 
    time: "2016-5-16
    total: 3322
}
...
]
```

I'm trying to filter on the x-axis with the brush, however, since I don't have every single date, if I brush in a small range, the filter handler seems to return an empty array for my filters

I've set up my line chart's x-axis like so:

```
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
```

is there a way to make it so a user can only filter on dates that are in the dataset?

I would like the brush to snap to dates in the dataset.

it seems like whats happening is that you are able to brush between ticks..so it doesn't know what it selected.

Comment: Are you looking for [chart.round()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#round__anchor)?

Comment: this looks good. But is there a way to round to values in the dataset? otherwise i'll have to write an error message that says "please extend the brush range" which isn't very ideal.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of any easy way to do that. Wouldn't be too hard to create a handler so that if brushing results in nothing selected it resets to no brush.

Comment: @Gordon how do you clear a brush?

Comment: Okay I'll answer the easier question later today. I did think about your snap-to-data question and I really like the idea. However there are tricky questions about which end of the brush should snap, and an efficient way to find the nearest bar.

Comment: @Gordon Regarding your question about which end should snap, both ends should snap to the nearest data point if both ends haven't selected anything.

Comment: One of the difficulties is that there may not be data on one end of the brush. So you would start dragging and the brush appears somewhere else, not under the mouse at all!

Comment: what about only allowing people to drag from one data point to another? https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/composite.html in this example, if you hover over the lines, you can see a circle on datapoints. It should be possible to only drag by selecting those circles to the next circle?

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen an interface like that but it might work. Functionally it sounds sort of the same as the answer I gave below, except that it would only start the brush when the mouse is over a "dot". There are probably more details, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the easier question: How do I create a brush that will not allow nothing to be selected?

In other words, if the brush contains no data, do not allow it to take.

There are two parts to the solution. First, since any chart with a brush will remove the old filter and then add the new filter, we can set up the [addFilterHandler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#addFilterHandler__anchor) to reject any filter that does not contain non-zero bins:

```
spendHistChart.addFilterHandler(function(filters, filter) {
  var binsIn = spendHistChart.group().all().filter(function(kv) {
    return filter.isFiltered(kv.key) && kv.value;
  });
  console.log('non-empty bins in range', binsIn.length);
  return binsIn.length ? [filter] : [];
});
```

That's the straightforward part, and incidentally I think you could probably modify it to snap the brush to existing data. (I haven't tried it, though.)

The more tricky part is that this won't get rid of the brush, it just doesn't apply the filter. So the chart will end up in an inconsistent state.

We need to detect when the brush action has finished, and if there is no filter at that point, explicitly tell the chart to clear the filter:

```
spendHistChart.brush().on('brushend.no-empty', function() {
  if(!spendHistChart.filters().length)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        spendHistChart.filterAll().redraw();
    }, 100);
});
```

We need a brief delay here, because if we respond to `brushend` synchronously, the chart may still be responding to it, causing bickering and dissatisfaction.

As a bonus, you get kind of a "nah-ah" animation because of the [unintentional remove-brush animation](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1071).

[image: no empty brush nah ah]

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/jcqtn9h2/23/)